# How to install a Windows Update from an MSI package

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.5

Is there a way to install Windows Updates from an MSI package installation??

I am authoring an MSI package in WiX which requires some Windows Updates to be installed in the machine.

Answer (score 4):

Windows Installer was intended for the installation of Windows applications, rather than Windows updates or service packs. Your setup application may be able to invoke the [Windows Update Stand-alone Installer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934307) (Wusa.exe) and the [Windows Update Agent (WUA) API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387292.aspx). However, the package developer would need to consider what their users would think of package that updates the system.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will try this option and see how it goes.